# Media Queries Applied for Portrait and Landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently building a small website including RWD features to enable it to work well on mobile devices.

My media queries seem to work correctly in portrait mode. However, when I rotate the devices the rules don't seem to apply any more.

**Portrait Mode (320x480)**

[image: Rendered in Mozilla]

Using the code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)
```

The same media query renders this in

**Landscape Mode (480x320)**

[image]

As you can probably make out, my media queries adjust the font size depending on the width of the screen. Strangely, the font in the Landscape view does not change even though the media query applies to it too.

The full code of the media queries:

```
/*................................
MEDIA QUERIES - Phones
..................................*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)    {

/*............................
FONTS
..............................*/

html    {
    font-size: 70%;

}

p.promo {
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

}

/*..............................
LAYOUT
................................*/

.clientLogo {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    background: $moondust;
}

/* Phones - Landscape */

/*................................
MEDIA QUERIES - Tablets
..................................*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)    {

/*............................
FONTS
..............................*/

html    {
    font-size: 85%;
}

p.promo {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

/*.............................
LAYOUT
...............................*/

.clientLogo {
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    background: $moondust;

}

}

/*................................
MEDIA QUERIES - Desktops
..................................*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)   {

/*............................
FONTS
..............................*/

html    {
    font-size: 100%;
}


/*...............................
LAYOUT
.................................*/

.clientLogo {
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    background: $moondust;

}

}
```

Comment: Is it just the font rule that doesn't work? Do any other rules in the same media query execute in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Comment: How will this render for instance on an iPhone 5 at 320x480 landscape? From your media query it seems that both conditions have to be true due to the "and" operator